# How come the stargate doesn't burn through the iris?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, wormhole

I may just not remember this, but doesn't the Stargate horizon destroy everything in its way when the gate is activated? How then, can the Stargate's Iris stay in tact?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### The iris is so close to the event horizon that it disrupts the vortex.

It's a handwave, sure, but the official explanation is that "if the event horizon is blocked to within a few microns, the vortex will be suppressed." ([source](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Stargate#Technical_specifications))

This works because they make a distinction between the vortex and the event horizon. The event horizon is the near end of the wormhole; the vortex is the momentary eruption of destructive energy which heralds the creation of the wormhole. When a solid object is extremely close to the event horizon when the wormhole forms, the associated energy burst is suppressed.

Once the wormhole is established, the iris has the same effect on any matter coming through; it disrupts whatever comes out of the event horizon, preventing matter from forming just the same way it suppressed the vortex.

Comment: hmm..but they are able to make the wormhole..

Good to know, I didn't remember them saying that. I do remember them saying it would keep matter from reintegrating.

Comment: @TheDoctor Added a bit about the difference between the event horizon, the wormhole, and the vortex.

Comment: AFAIK, the kawoosh is generally understood to be excess energy actually coming out of the event horizon, same as any object passing through.  The Nox were able to suppress the kawoosh entirely.

Comment: @Izkata, S2E21, _1969_: When SG-1 is catapulted into the future (near-abandoned) SGC, Cassandra also uses a device which dials the gate and suppresses the flush.

Comment: @TheDoctor - there's an episode (can't remember which one) where they (possibly only talk about) set the iris back a little bit and it completely blocks the wormhole from forming

Comment: @HorusKol - One I can remember off the top of my head is the episode in which Teal'c is trapped within the Stargate after getting his revenge on the Goa'uld Tanith. Doing so is the equivalent of burying a gate.

Comment: On the one hand, burying a stargate prevents it from being used - presumably because the vortex is suppressed. On the other hand, a stargate was buried due to a meteor impact in the episode "A Hundred Days" but it was successfully activated; the "kawoosh" excavated a chamber from within which Teal'c was able to dig up to the surface. How does all this get handwaved?

Comment: @AnthonyX - That actually follows all the rules and they explained it in the show.  The gate was covered while still active, and so when it shut off, it effectively worked as a constant iris, allowing dial-ins but no entry.  They then used a trick a goauld used on their iris (subatomic particle bombardment) to eat away at the material on the other side until there was JUST enough space for a kawoosh to form.

Answer (score 4):

The destructive wave you see is not the event horizon, it is the "unstable vortex of forming a wormhole" aka ["the Kawoosh"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/9.19_%22Crusade_Part_1%22_Transcript).

> CARTER: Well since you disintegrated the Alteran communication stones and the base terminal in the kawoosh—
>
> MITCHELL: I'm sorry, the what?
>
> CARTER: The unstable vortex of a forming wormhole. Kawoosh.
>
> MITCHELL: Don't think I've ever heard you call it that before.
>
> CARTER: Really?
>
> MITCHELL: Don't get me wrong, it's good.
>
> CARTER: No, I mean, I'm sure—

The Iris sits micrometers above the event horizon preventing matter or anything else (even the Kawoosh) from forming. Sam explains it in ["The Enemy Within"](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/1.03_%22The_Enemy_Within%22_Transcript).

> DANIEL: So this iris is going to hold right?
>
> CARTER: Pure titanium. Less than three micrometers from the event horizon. It won't even allow matter to fully reintegrate.
>
> JACK: So this iris is going to hold right?

Comment: Initially titanium but later trinium.